# Pulling one directory above selected directory msoFileDialogFolderPicker

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use msoFileDialogFolderPicker in an excel macro to select the save location for my filepath. When I execute the code successfully creates the multiple csvs however, they land a directory above the location that I have selected in the msoFileDialogFolderPicker. I have tried using 2 for .selectedItems(2) considering once I land in the default directory I have to drill in one level before selecting my final folder destination with no success.

```
    Sub SplitRowsToMultipleCSVs()
    
    
    Const HeaderRow As Integer = 1
    Dim FolderPath As String
    
    Dim iRow As Integer, startSheet As Worksheet, tmpSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NumRows As Integer
    Dim s As String
      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Ticket Number", Type:=2)
    
    FolderPath = GetFolder()
    
    NumRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iRow = HeaderRow + 1
    Set startSheet = ActiveSheet
    Do Until iRow > NumRows
        Set tmpSheet = Worksheets.Add
        'copy the header
        startSheet.Range(HeaderRow & ":" & HeaderRow).EntireRow.Copy tmpSheet.Range("A1")
        'copy the data
        startSheet.Range(iRow & ":" & (iRow)).EntireRow.Copy tmpSheet.Range("A2")
        'save tmpSheet to CSV file
        tmpSheet.Move
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=FolderPath & "BillingNAVSetup_" & s & "_" & (iRow - 1) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS
            .Close True
        End With
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


Function GetFolder() As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    '.InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I think you need a path separator after `FolderPath` in your file name.

Comment: Thank you @Kostas. Had to look into what you were referring to but your breadcrumb helped to find the solution. 

Updated code to:

` .SaveAs Filename:=FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & "BillingNAVSetup_" & s & "_" & (iRow - 1) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS `

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. For some reason I couldn't write the backslash character in my comment.